TypeError: Cannot use scipy.linalg.eigh for sparse A with k >= N. Use scipy.linalg.eigh(A.toarray()) or reduce k. BERTopic
'''
from bertopic import BERTopic
# Define seed words for topics
seed_words = [
    ['software', 'programming', 'Python', 'Java', 'machine learning', 'data visualization'],
    ['project management', 'leadership'],
    ['healthcare', 'medical research', 'patient care', 'disease prevention']
]

# Sample documents (text data)
documents = [
    "This is about software development and programming languages like Python and Java.",
    "Finance and banking are important topics in the economy.",
    "Project management and leadership skills are essential for success.",
    "Healthcare and medical research focus on patient care and disease prevention."
]

# Initialize BERTopic model with seed_topic_list
model = BERTopic(seed_topic_list=seed_words)

# Fit and transform documents to obtain topics and probabilities
topics, probabilities = model.fit_transform(documents)`enter code here`

# Display the assigned topics for each document
for i, (doc, topic) in enumerate(zip(documents, topics)):
    print(f"Document {i+1}: Topic {topic} - '{doc}'")

'''
**
Error
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/_eigen/arpack/arpack.py:1600: RuntimeWarning: k >= N for N * N square matrix. Attempting to use scipy.linalg.eigh instead.
warnings.warn("k >= N for N * N square matrix. "
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/_eigen/arpack/arpack.py:1600: RuntimeWarning: k >= N for N * N square matrix. Attempting to use scipy.linalg.eigh instead.
warnings.warn("k >= N for N * N square matrix. "
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/bertopic/_bertopic.py in _reduce_dimensionality(self, embeddings, y, partial_fit)
3471                 y = np.array(y) if y is not None else None
-> 3472                 self.umap_model.fit(embeddings, y=y)
3473             except TypeError:
14 frames
TypeError: Cannot use scipy.linalg.eigh for sparse A with k >= N. Use scipy.linalg.eigh(A.toarray()) or reduce k.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/_eigen/arpack/arpack.py in eigsh(A, k, M, sigma, which, v0, ncv, maxiter, tol, return_eigenvectors, Minv, OPinv, mode)
1603
1604         if issparse(A):
-> 1605             raise TypeError("Cannot use scipy.linalg.eigh for sparse A with "
1606                             "k >= N. Use scipy.linalg.eigh(A.toarray()) or"
1607                             " reduce k.")
TypeError: Cannot use scipy.linalg.eigh for sparse A with k >= N. Use scipy.linalg.eigh(A.toarray()) or reduce k.**

did you find any solution? I am also facing similar issue
